# Error in curl::handle_setopt(handle, .list = req$options) : Option seekfunction (20167) has unknown or unsupported type

Tags: r, httr

When trying to send some files to SharePoint, the error message appeared

**Error in curl::handle_setopt(handle, .list = req$options) :
Option seekfunction (20167) has unknown or unsupported type.**

The cause of the issue is related to updates in the httr and curl packages.

I had installed httr package version 1.4.7 however without also installing at the same time package "curl" version >= 5.0.2 which caused the above error when trying to upload files to SharePoint.  Curl version 5.0.2 isn't yet available for windows so rolling back to version 1.4.6 of "httr" works with the latest version of "curl" currently available of 5.0.0.

When httr v 1.4.7 is installed, curl >= 5.0.2 should be installed at the same time.

Comment: is this an issue with httr package you want to report ? I think you or someone else have already reported there. https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/746. posting this link here for someone landing here to be able to follow up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to pin_write to Posit Connect, and I fixed it by simply close and restart all sessions again.